# ClickOnce deployed application can't find external DLL

Tags: c#, winforms, dll, clickonce

I have this WinForms application that uses an external dll file (Winppla.dll) so I can print tags in my Argox printer. Since I cannot add the dll file as a reference to the project, I use the command `[DllImport("Winppla.dll")]` on my class.
When I run the project in Visual Studio, it works perfectly.
Then I published my application using ClickOnce and when I try to run the application, I get the message error saying that the Winppla.dll could not be found, even though I am running it on my machine.

I tried to:

- copy the file to the bin folder of the project before publishing
- copy the file to the packages folder of the application before publishing
- copy the file to the latest version folder on the Application Files folder (on the publishing location of the application)
- add the file as a resource on the project
- add a folder with the file as a Reference Path on the project

but none of these worked.

This project also uses SAP CrystalReports, and it works just fine.

Any ideas about how to make it work?

Comment: What happens when you copy the Winppla dll into the folder where the Application is being run?

Comment: I get the same error, saying that the resource could not be found

Comment: Go to your Project Properties, click on the publish tab and there should be a button there for Application Files. Is it listed in there?   If not there is a check box that says show all files.  if its not listed in there add it to the project as a reference and then see if it is shown in there after that.  Once its shown in there you need to change its publish status to include.

Comment: It is not listed there :/ I can't add it to the project as reference, I receive a message saying "A reference to '...\Winppla.dll' file could not be added. Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component". That's why I import it using DllImport command

Comment: Try just moving it into the project folder.  It wont show initially, but there is a option in solution explorer to show all files.  It will show up in your solution then with a dotted line icon next to it.  If you right click and say include in your project it should then be listed in your Application files for Publish.

Comment: Same error :/ if it helps, the error says there is a HRESULT exception 0x8007007E

Comment: Perhaps you can add some code to copy that DLL for a network share down to the  ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory and then point your DLL import to that folder to look for it if it doesnt exist.  That folder will protect against updates to the application as well since Click ONce applications are a little weird and run from the local app directory and have an obfuscated folder.  Either that or point to a network share.

Comment: IT WORKED! I placed the file on a shared folder of my machine and wrote the path in all DllImport commands, and it worked! Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad that worked I would work on making a more "Enterprise" option instead of a share off your own PC, if there is a PC or Network share path I would go that route instead.

Comment: I will try to put the file on our server, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @Bearcat9425 instructions in the comments section of the question, I finally solved the problem:

1. Copy the file to the project folder and include it on the project
   (on Solution Explorer, click on 'Show All Files', then right-click in the file and select 'Include In Project')
2. Mark the file as one of the application files on my publish tab
   (right-click on my project and select 'Properties', then go to Publish tab and click on 'Application Files' and make sure the Winppla.dll is marked as 'Include')
3. Copy the Winppla.dll file to a shared folder in our server (I placed it on the same folder where I placed the setup  of my application)
4. On each DllImport command write the complete path to the file shared location: `[DllImport(@"\\the-path-on-the-server\Winppla.dll")]`
5. Publish!